# Unusual tricky situation in java beginners

Tags: java

This program is for finding a number with maximum divisor between 1 and 10000. No matter if two numbers have max but we will print only one.

```
int integerWithMax =1; // first, 1 as integer with max divisor
int maxDivisor = 1;   // 1 has max divisor
for (int i = 2; i <= 10000; i++) {
    int j;
    int divisorCount = 0;
    for (j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        if((i % j) == 0) {
            divisorCount++;
        }
    }
    if (divisorCount > maxDivisor) {
        // maxDivisor = divisorCount; //why do I need this line if I need only integerWithMax 
        integerWithMax = i;
    }
}
System.out.print("The integer with max divisor is "+integerWithMax );
```

The problem here is if I uncomment `maxDivisor` it will give correct integer with `maxDivisor = 7560` but if I comment it, `integerWithMax` will output `10000`.

Question is why should I assign to `maxDivisor` if I have to find integer with max divisor, i.e. `integerWithMax`?

Comment: Please change your title to reflect the actual issue.

Comment: Paper , pen, may be good idea Initially !

Answer (score 0):

This code is finding the number between 1 and 10000 that has the highest number of divisors.  I have commented the code so you can understand what is happening.

```
int integerWithMax = 1; // say that 1 is the integer with most divisors
int maxDivisor = 1;   // 1 has only a single divisor, itself

for (int i = 2; i <= 10000; i++) { // test each integer 2-10000
    int j;
    int divisorCount = 0;     // keep track of the number of divisors for integer i
    for (j = 1; j < i; j++) { // for each number smaller than i
        if((i % j) == 0) {    // if j is a divisor
            divisorCount++;   // increment the count of divisors
        }
    }
    // if my integer has a higher number of divisors than have previously been seen
    if (divisorCount > maxDivisor) {
        maxDivisor = divisorCount; // keep track of the new highest number of divisors
        integerWithMax = i;        // keep track of the integer
    }
}
System.out.print("The integer with max divisor is "+integerWithMax );
```

If you comment out `maxDivisor = divisorCount;` then the `if` statement is always asking "does this integer have more than one divisor?", which is true for all all numbers that are not prime.